# Getting the key corresponding to a particular value in an associative array

Tags: bash, associative-array

I declare an associative array:

```
declare -A array=([a]=blue [b]=red [c]=yellow)
```

now I can do:

```
echo ${array[@]}  --> blue red yellow
```

or

```
echo ${array[b]}  --> red
```

or

```
echo ${!array[@]} --> a b c
```

Now I want to know only the key associated to `red` value.
Is there a way to detect just a single key?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple keys with the same value?

Comment: Related: [Inverting an associative array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/506891)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you'd want to get a list of keys that correspond to a particular value, and that you'd like to store this list in an array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash
hash=(
    [k1]="hello world"
    [k2]="hello there"
    [k3]="hello world"
    [k4]=bumblebees
)

string="hello world"

keys=()
for key in "${!hash[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${hash[$key]} == "$string" ]]; then
        keys+=( "$key" )
    fi
done

printf 'Keys with value "%s":\n' "$string"
printf '\t%s\n' "${keys[@]}"
```

This walks through the list of keys and tests the value corresponding to each key against the string we're looking for.  If there is a match, we store the key in the `keys` array.

At the end, the found keys are outputted.

The output of this script would be

```
Keys with value "hello world":
        k1
        k3
```

Comment: This worked well for me. Adjusted for my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `zsh` shell (note that `zsh` had associative array support decades before `bash`) has operators for that:

- `${hash[(R)pattern]}` expands to the *values* that match the pattern.
- `${(k)hash[(R)pattern]}` expands to the keys where the corresponding value matches the pattern.
- `${(k)hash[(Re)string]}` same except the *string* is treated as an `e`xact string, not a pattern even if it contains wildcard characters.

So:

```
print -r -- ${(k)array[(Re)red]}
```

Will print the *non-empty* keys where the value is `red`.

To include the empty keys, use:

```
$ typeset -A array
$ array=(a blue b red c yellow '' red)
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${(@k)array[(Re)red]}"
<>
<b>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but you could do:

```
for k in "${!array[@]}"; do
    [[ ${array[$k]} == red ]] && printf '%s\n' "$k"
done
```

This will loop through the indices of the array and check each if their value is `red`, if so it will print the index.

Alternatively and also not pretty you could use `sed`:

```
declare -p array | sed -n 's/.*\[\(.*\)\]="red".*/\1/p'
```

This will print the array as declared and find the index for the value of `red` and print that.

Comment: I needed to delete the blank after the first star to make it work.

Comment: declare -p arr | sed -n 's/.*\\[\\(.*\\)\\]="red" .*/\1/p'

Comment: @pietroletti: That command produces an error in every version of `sed` I have.

Comment: I have sed version 4.4.  Your first regex is working for 'yellow' and 'blue' but not for 'red'.  Deleting the space after the first star it works for all values. I'm trying to understand why...

Comment: It may be that red is the first value displayed when you do `declare -p array` in which case there is no space between `(` and `[b]=...`